# changing data type of column in ssas (date compatibility between ssms/ssas/ssrs?)

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

I have made a cube that I am using to make reports. Two of the parameters I am using are `@Year` and `Decile` in SSRS.

Problem 1:

Data type of Decile in table (ssms) is tinyint, in SSAS its byte and in ssrs it takes text as the data type in the parameter. I thought if I could change the data type in ssas it will take int in SSRS

Problem 2:

Data type of Year in date table (ssms) is smallint, in ssas its int16 but in SSRS when I define that parameter as integer it throws an error, and when I define it as text it runs fine.

Can someone highlight why this might be?

Which code do you want to see? See image below

EDIT: [image]

Comment: Can you connect to SSAS inside SQL Server Profiler and then try to run the report? I would like to see the Query Begin event from profiler including the XML at the end of the query where it specifies the parameters passed to your query.

Comment: @GregGalloway So I started sql server profiler and a new trace on my ssas which bit do you want to see? This is totally new to me sadly

Comment: run the report in the report designer. I assume some Query Begin events will come through. Copy off the text including the XML parameters.

Comment: ohk so i will run the report and run the ssas trace on sql profiler?

Comment: right. Run the report while the trace is running in Profiler

Comment: I have edited the question with the image

Comment: no errors? And please find the query where there is a parameter issue and click on that Query Begin row and copy out all the text from the bottom pane including the XML.

Comment: it didnt give any errors, and I cant point the parameters section I looked through it all. confusing for me at this stage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108286/discussion-between-faiz-and-greggalloway).

Comment: any luck capturing this?